# Upgrading Jenkins Windows Native Package Manually

Tags: jenkins

we are using Jenkins 1.527 as a Windows service. We installed it using its Windows native package installer. Now We want to manually update it to the latest version. We don't want to lose our currently used job configurations. Is simply uninstalling and installing the new package enough to accomplish this task ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I downloaded a Long Term Support Release and ran the msi installer. It seems to have worked, but the version is being reported incorrectly as my previous older version. This older version is still  listed in config.xml - should the config.xml file normally get updated automatically when I run the Windows installer?

Comment: Correction: I attempted to install 1.609.1 LTS, Jenkins about page reports 1.562, config.xml says 1.572. I'm confused.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out; just replace the updated war file with the old one :)

Comment: ... and don't use the Windows installer at all. Worked for me too.

Answer (score 8):

Nice post [here](https://guyharwood.co.uk/2016/05/25/upgrading-jenkins-on-windows/) on the same.

***NOTE:** ALWAYS A GOOD IDEA TO KEEP BACKUP*

### In a nutshell

- Stop the Jenkins windows service
- Rename `war` directory to `war.bak`
- Rename `jenkins.war` to `jenkins.war.bak`
- Copy new `jenkins.war` into Jenkins directory
- Start Jenkins windows service
- Observe creation of `war` directory which will now contain contents of `jenkins.war` archive
- Navigate to Jenkins home page, at which point you will be informed that Jenkins is preparing your installation
- Once complete, test your existing jobs to verify compatibility
- Navigate to `Manage Jenkins` via the menu and Action any notifications displayed - plugins, data format conversions etc.
- Delete `jenkins.war.bak` file and `war.bak` folder

Answer (score 0):

Method-1
You can upgrade either going to the manage Jenkins and click on button - Or Upgrade Automatically for the latest version of jenkins [image: Manage Jenkins]

Method-2

- Go to `C:\Program Files\Jenkins` and replace jenkins.war file with the desired jenkins version.
  Jenkins war version's are available here: https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/
- Restart jenkins service.